# Navigate the forum

Tags: discussion

I need to understand how to navigate the page. How do I post a question? where do I go to find the answers? How do I follow a thread...
As you can see, I'm an absolute beginner.
Thanks
rye37@cox.net

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answers in the FAQ section.

Here is it: https://meta.askubuntu.com/faq.

If you still have some questions, please add a comment to my answer.

I hope this helped you,
Daniel

Comment: I think rye37 is talking about here rather than UbuntuForums.

Comment: @Oli Okay, edited the link.